# Object object рендер v-for from store localStorage?

Tags: vue.js

Как мне отрендерить обьект с localStorage ? Обьект - там его храню в localStorage а именно в state

Если он у меня в формате Object object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, при сохранении он серилизовался в строку '[Object object]'.
Если хотите хранить объекты в localStogage преобразуйте их в json например, а после чтения обратно в Object. Связи при этом умрут, поэтому объект должен быть нормализован

```
const a ={name:'Вася',lastname:"Пупкин"};
localStorage.setItem('state',JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')));
```

Comment: жаль я уже делал но спасибо